# Estrutura PostgreSQL 9.3 CentOS

Tags: postgresql, centos

Gostaria de saber o que é e o que faz parte desse diretório *base*.

> /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/base/17500/18037
>
> /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/base/17500/18170
>
> /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/base/17500/18168
>
> /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/base/17500/18169
>
> /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/base/17500/17614.1
>
> /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/base/17500/17614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/storage-file-layout.html#PGDATA-CONTENTS-TABLE), `/var/lib/pgsql/data` é o diretório de dados de agrupamento onde fica armazenado os dados necessários para um agrupamento de bancos de dados, geralmente referenciado como *PGDATA*, devido ao nome da variável de ambiente que pode ser utilizada para defini-lo. Esse diretório contém vários subdiretórios e arquivos de controle, como o [`pg_database`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalog-pg-database.html)  e [`postgresql.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/config-setting.html).

O Subdiretório *base* contém subdiretórios por banco de dados, para cada banco de dados do agrupamento existe um subdiretório dentro de *PGDATA/base*, com nome correspondente ao [**OID**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html) do banco de dados em `pg_database`. Este subdiretório é o local padrão para os arquivos do banco de dados, em particular, os catálogos do sistema do banco de dados são armazenados neste subdiretório. Cada tabela e índice é armazenado em um arquivo separado, com nome correspondente ao número do *filenode* da tabela ou do índice, que pode ser encontrado em [`pg_class.relfilenode`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/catalog-pg-class.html).

Quando uma tabela ou um índice excede 1Gb, este é dividido em segmentos de até 1 Gb. O nome do primeiro arquivo de segmento é o mesmo do *filenode*, os arquivos subsequentes são chamados de *filenode.1*, *filenode.2*, por exemplo *17614.1*. Essa organização evita problemas em plataformas que possuem limitação de tamanho de arquivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado QMechanic73 .